# Final single operation after mergeMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a stream like this:

```
this.myService.getUsersFromServer().pipe(                // gets all users
  concatAll(),                                           // concat for Api calls
  filter((user) => user.role === "moderator")            // filter in moderators  
  mergeMap((user) => this.myService.deleteUser(user.id)) // delete all moderators
).subscribe();
```

What I now want to do is to make a final api call, before the subscription, to update the list of users, like this:

```
[...],  // delete all moderators
finalCallOperator(() => this.myService.getUsersFromServer())
```

**My question**

What operator should I use to make a **single** call after a list of operations? If I work with `switchMap` in this case, I will have multiple executions of `this.myService.getUsersFromServer()`, all canceled except the last.

**EDIT**

Code of `getUsersFromServer` function:

```
getUsersFromServer() {
  let req = new HttpRequest<Users[]>(
    'GET',
    `/users`
  );

  return this.http.request<Users[]>(req);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code for your `getUsersFromServer()` function. I'm not sure you're doing what you expect ...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this call returns an array of users ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Okay, let me answer you then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the following:

```js
this.myService.getUsersFromServer().pipe(         
  // map to filtered array       
  map(users => users.filter(user => user.role === "moderator")),
  // map to array of delete HTTP requests
  map(users => users.map(user => this.myService.deleteUser(user.id)),
  // flatten + run in parallel
  mergeMap(deleteRequests$ => forkJoin(deleteRequests$)),
  // map to users request
  mergeMap(() => this.myService.getUsersFromServer())
).subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But I don't fully understand, why the extra map (the second one) is neccessary. Why can't i just write `mergeMap(users => forkJoin(this.myService.deleteUser(user.id))`? I mean, it does not work, but I don't understand the stream flow on this point.

Comment: you can indeed spare a couple of operators, I used more lines for the sake of readability